# how to have responsives images with Markdown on angular?

Tags: angular, markdown

I'm loading a Markdown (md) file into an angular page, and i don't manage to make images responsives on mobile.

I've found some tutorials that's are using Jquery to do so, but as i'm with angular i don't want to use Jquery.

I've tried to load img inside the markdown files with :

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

but it's not working.

The Markdown file is loaded into a NgOnInit function :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.post = './assets/blog/post/' + params['id'] + '.md';
    });
  }
```

Inside my html i use

```
<markdown [src]="post"></markdown>
```

to display the page.

Comment: you could always use scss to target the images within the markdown?

Comment: I can't use SCSS of my angular page, but it works if i use the SCSS of the parent component.

Comment: So you can manipulate the images from there?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem using CSS. 
But the CSS was working in the parent component and not the current component.

```
<style>
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
</style>
```